# Flutter TextField not centering when its Container shortened in GridView

Tags: flutter, gridview, textfield, center

I'm trying to create a grid of TextFields that are centered in Containers. Works great until the grid tiles get a bit squat:

[image]

As you can see, the text is too low. When the aspect ratio makes the tiles a bit taller, they center properly.

How can I keep the text centered in short grid tiles? Here the code on dartpad:

[Dartpad version](https://dartpad.dev/d7dfae3abef05248d780a24673ccb2bc)

The dartpad code is this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: GridView.count(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            childAspectRatio: 10,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
            mainAxisSpacing: 0.0,
            crossAxisSpacing: 0.0,
            children: <Widget>[
              EditableButton('Hello'),
              EditableButton('World'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class EditableButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final controller;

  EditableButton(String text) : controller = TextEditingController(text: text);

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.5),
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.deepPurple,
          child: Center(
            child: TextField(
              controller: controller,
              decoration:
                  InputDecoration.collapsed(hintText: 'Tag description'),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.top,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 16,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could help, instead of use a InputDecoration.collapsed use only InputDecoration and manipulate the padding with the [ContentPadding property](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration/contentPadding.html)
 as follows:

```
TextField(
          controller: controller,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: 'Tag description',
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
          ),
```

Comment: Thanks Luis! Worked great. Interestingly, I didn't find I needed the contentPadding -- just your unnamed constructor suggestion. I'm probably missing something, but is there a reason you had it there? (I updated my Dartpad version with the change, plus made the underline borders invisible, which is why I had been using the named constructor.)

Comment: Great!, Well the only difference is that a InputDecoration.Collpased defines an InputDecorator that is the same size as the input field, doesn't include a border by default because it sets the isCollapsed property to true and with that it cannot have a labelText, errorText, or an icon.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

`TextField( textAlign: TextAlign.center, decoration: InputDecoration( contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0), ), )`